# Autocad 2014 - Positioning electrical objects for plans (icons and symbols, not actual objects)

Tags: symbols, autocad

I am using Autocad to design my home. I am at a phase where I want to set the location for the switches, lighting fixtures, power sockets, communication sockets etc. I am thinking of something like this http://www.the-house-plans-guide.com/electrical-blueprint-symbols.html.
I am not interested in placing specific lighting fixtures or rendering them, just putting the symbol and distances for the symbol.
I can use Autocad Electrical, but that's a GIANT overshoot.
What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand.  You want to do this through the API or something?

Comment: You are missing an actual question about programming.